# Toggle Modal on notification click

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm trying to make my service worker file trigger a bootstrap modal on push notification click - but I'm struggling to get it to work. I understand that the service worker can't access the DOM, so how can I trigger such an event such as a modal?
I've tried calling a function from an external file, however it just says it's undefined. I've also tried using a listener within my main js file, but that just doesn't trigger.

```js
this.notificationclick = function(event) {) //doesn't work.
```

I know my service worker triggers, because I can log the event to the console. I also know the file the function lives in is also loading as other code within that file runs.

This is my code for the function I'm trying to call:

```js
const showModal = (array) => {
  document.getElementById('notificationModalTitle').innerHTML = array[0];
  document.getElementById('notificationModalBody').innerHTML = array[1];
  const img = array[2];
  const icon = array[3];

$('#notificationModal').modal()
}
```

This is the code within my `sw.js` file that I've tried using for toggling the modal.

```js
this.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(e) {
  //event triggers, but function is undefined.
  showModal(["test", "testdesc", "test", "test"])
  console.log(e);
});
```

Thanks in advance.